# IntelliJ Idea + AEM Plugin + TypeScript compiler issue

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, compilation, aem, intellij-plugin

IntelliJ IDEA 2019, running AEM server as localhost and a filewatcher that transforms .ts files into .js files.
Whenever a .ts file is saved, filewatcher triggers upload to AEM server so changes take effect, however for some reason, instead of compiling and triggering because of 1 changed file, it logs ALL .ts files as "changed" and tries pushing them onto server, making build time go beyond 20 seconds before finally updating server.

What might be the cause? I've searched every single setting in IntelliJ and nothing seems to be the case, even scoping triggerable files down to opened files.

Comment: Isn't that "just" a TypeScript compilation issue? It basically depends on what the build script is doing. If all files "appear to be changed", because files were touched, you get a lot of changed files. You need to provide more insights and code.

Comment: @FlorianSalihovic It's the second week I'm using IntelliJ in my life and I haven't yet got deep into it's systems. I'll try to see if it's the compiler that is buggy.

Comment: IntelliJ is not compiling - TSC is compiling the TypeScript code and it is quite unlikely, that the compiler is the issue. My bet is on the build script.

Comment: what does your file watcher look like?

Answer (score 0):

So basically we removed filewatcher at all and used `npm i -g typescript` files from '/node_modules/, with IntelliJ TS settings set to compile on change & current file only. That fixed the issue.